# ORM and validation

Tags: php, validation, orm

I want to implement an ORM and validation libraries for it. Please suggest me how start work. Or suggest any developed library from where I got any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a look at existing ORM libraries, see what kind of functionality they provide, and the way they are implemented.... then decide whether you want to re-invent the wheel or not

Answer (score 0):

Try [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) wich is a great ORM. There are a bunch of others its difficult to suggest without knowing your level of knowledge and environment (frameworks?).